# Google analytics reporting dimensions & metrics are incompatible

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We have custom dimension define in [Google Analytics Data API v1Beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) for extracting data from Google Analytics GA4 account.

This worked fine till yesterday.

Error:

> Please remove customEvent:institution_id to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

```
POST - https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/{propertyId}:runReport
```

Body

```
{
  "dateRanges": [
    {
      "startDate": "2022-08-29",
      "endDate": "2022-12-07"
    }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "name": "customEvent:institution_id"
    },
    {
      "name": "pagePathPlusQueryString"
    }
  ],
  "dimensionFilter": {
    "andGroup": {
      "expressions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "fieldName": "customEvent:institution_id",
            "inListFilter": {
              "values": [
                "47339486-a1e5-47be-abce-e4270af23rte"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "fieldName": "pagePathPlusQueryString",
            "stringFilter": {
              "matchType": "PARTIAL_REGEXP",
              "value": "/clip/.+",
              "caseSensitive": false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "screenPageViews"
    }
  ],
  "metricAggregations": [
    "TOTAL"
  ],
  "limit": "10000"
}
```

Comment: You say you are using the reporting API for universal analytics.    Yet you linking dimension and metrics explorer for ga4.    These are two different systems which are not completable.     Pick a system UA or GA4

Comment: @DaImTo system was running more than year now. This specific issue happen on yesterday. Basically we are calling APIs on Nodejs

analyticsData.properties.runReport

Comment: Please edit your question include [example]  I need to see the full error you are getting

Comment: Have you tried removing customEvent:institution_id?  The error message seams to imply that you cant mix custom events this way.

Comment: This was working fine in production and no recent changes.
If I remove filter and metrics both it working fine. 

But that is not what I need I need to filer by custom field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250230/discussion-between-sandun-tharaka-and-daimto).

Comment: I can send a ping out to the team to find out if there were any changes that may have caused this.  Remember its a beta api.

Comment: I am facing similar issue since yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/a/75385513/649868 Need inputs @linda-lawton-daimto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimensions that include the query string like `pagePathPlusQueryString` are only compatible with a limited set of dimensions & metrics.

This changed was announced [2022-09-13 Schema compatibility changes announcement.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/changelog#2022-09-13_schema_compatibility_changes_announcement)

It went live earlier this week. So the cause if the error is that the `"customEvent:institution_id"` dimension is not compatible with `"pagePathPlusQueryString"`.

Comment: @damlto Thanks for checking with this analytics team. 
So What Do you think use of pagePath instead of pagePathPlusQueryString ?

Comment: Yes I would try that I think its the closest your going to get.