# Google analytics 4 reporting dimensions & metrics are incompatible using python

Tags: python, api, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We have custom dimension define in Google Analytics Data API v1Beta for extracting data from Google Analytics GA4 account.
I am trying to fetch eventCount metric with respect to date, campaignId, campaignName and eventName using python. I want to know what is the eventCount for different eventName in different campaignName. Is there any work around how can i fetch this data?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import DateRange
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import Dimension
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import Metric
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import RunReportRequest

client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
## Format Report - run_report method
def format_report(request):
    response = client.run_report(request)
    # Row index
    row_index_names = [header.name for header in response.dimension_headers]
    row_header = []
    for i in range(len(row_index_names)):
        row_header.append([row.dimension_values[i].value for row in response.rows])
    row_index_named = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(np.array(row_header), names = np.array(row_index_names))
    # Row flat data
    metric_names = [header.name for header in response.metric_headers]
    data_values = []
    for i in range(len(metric_names)):
        data_values.append([row.metric_values[i].value for row in response.rows])
    output = pd.DataFrame(data = np.transpose(np.array(data_values, dtype = 'f')), 
                          index = row_index_named, columns = metric_names)
    return output
request = RunReportRequest(
        property='properties/'+property_id,
        dimensions=[            
            Dimension(name="date"),
            Dimension(name="eventName"),
            Dimension(name="campaignId"),
            Dimension(name="campaignName")
                ],
        metrics=[         
            Metric(name="eventCount"),
            ],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-01-22", end_date="2023-01-25")],
    )
```

Error:

> InvalidArgument: 400 Please remove eventCount to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APcUN.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states not all dimensions and metrics are complatable.

In your case [eventcount](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#eventCount) is not compatible with `campaignId` or `campaignName` So to make this request work you must either remove `eventcount`, or remove `campaignId` or `campaignName`

I guess what I am saying is that you cant make that request, the data doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue where I am creating a custom report to fetch `itemListViewEvents` and `itemViewEvents` based on `itemId`

here's my logic:

```rb
require 'google/analytics/data'
require 'google/analytics/data/v1beta'
require 'google/analytics/data/v1beta/analytics_data'

class GoogleAnalyticsReportingApiService

  range = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::DateRange.new(
    start_date: Time.zone.today.to_date.to_s,
    end_date: 1.week.ago.to_date.to_s
  )

  metrics = [
    Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Metric.new(expression: 'itemListViews', name: 'itemListViewEvents'),
    Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Metric.new(expression: 'itemViews', name: 'itemViewEvents')
  ]

  dimension = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::Dimension.new(name: 'itemId')

  rr = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::RunReportRequest.new(
    property: analytics_property,
    dimensions: [dimension],
    metrics: metrics,
    date_ranges: [range],
    order_bys: [{desc: true, metric: {metric_name: 'itemViewEvents'}}],
    limit: 100000
  )
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
Google::Cloud::InvalidArgumentError: 3:Please remove itemId to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/. debug_error_string:{UNKNOWN:Error received from peer
```

and this is clearly outlined here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/announcements/20221201-compatibility-changes

Now the issue is, I just cannot use only `dimension` or `metrics` because the API Names are not supported either way (for example: `itemId` is not supported in Metric). Not sure how to to deal with this! More info here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/20138

[UPDATE Feb/15/23]

After trying my hands on Custom Events, Custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics, I ended up using alternate schema name for the Metrics fields.

The documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema helped me a lot and I was able to figure out that I can use `itemViewEvents` for `itemListViewEvents` and `itemsViewed` for `itemViewEvents`